# power automate desktop not connecting with browser extension

Tags: automation, browser-automation, power-automate-desktop

I have installed the latest versions of power automate desktop and browser extension, and I'm using the Microsoft Edge browser, before the latest update come, it worked perfectly, but after the update it not working.

every time I run the flow it shows this error:
"Failed to assume control of Microsoft Edge (Communication with browser failed. Try reloading extension)."

Answer (score 0):

With the new version you also have to make sure developer tools are enabled in your browser.

See the [information here about manifest v3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/power-automate/desktop-flows/manifest)

When I updated to the latest version of PAD I also had major issues lucky I was able to roll back to the previous version.

I'm aware this might not solve your issue, but the only way I could get mine working again was to uninstall 2.27 and reinstall 2.26, lucky I had the install for 2.26 as I couldn't find a previous version download link on the MS website anywhere.

Comment: anyway you could share the 2.26 install file on Dropbox or Google Drive, etc. I have the same issue and tons of broken automation flows that I need to run.